# Prove the statements or show counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> If $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is everywhere differentiable and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty$ then there is a point $x_0$ where $f'(x_0)=0$.

and

> If $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is everywhere differentiable and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\ell\in\mathbb R$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.

Hi all, I am not sure what the difference is between the two statements, and if both are true or not.
How would I go about proving them.
All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, the given condition implies that there exist $a<0$ and $b>0$ with $f(a)>f(0)$ and $f(b)>f(0)$. Now use the fact that $f$ assumes its minimum on the compact interval $[a,b]$.

For the second, consider $f(x)=e^{-x}\sin(e^x)$.

Answer (score 3):

The first one follows from the theorem that $$
 \text{if $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then for some $c \in [a,b]$ you have $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.}
$$
For your $f$, let $y_0 = f(0)$ and pick some $y > y_0$. Since $f$ is continuous (since it has a derivative) and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$, there's some $x_2 > 0$ with $f(x_2) = y$. Similarly, there is some $x_1 < 0$ with $f(x_1) = y$. Due to the theorem states above, there's then a $c \in [x_1,x_2]$ with $$
  f'(c) = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} = {y - y}{x_2-x_1} = 0 \text{.}
$$