# Is the function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> If $f_j:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous for $j=1,\ldots,n$, then so is the function $g$ defined by $$g(x)=\max\{f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)\}.$$ If $f_j:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous for each $j\in\Bbb N$, then so is the function $g$ defined by $$g(x)=\max\{f_j(x):j\in\Bbb N\}.$$

What is the difference between the two statements?
I know the first statement is true but can't seem to differentiate between the two.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the second statement there is an infinite, but countable, number of functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove the statements or show counterexample](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771366/prove-the-statements-or-show-counterexample)

Comment: Note that $\max$ is not even necessarily defined for an infinie set.

Comment: $f_{j}$ prescribed by $x\mapsto j$ is continuous, but...

Answer (score 2):

In the first question maximum is taken over a finite set. In the second question the maximum is taken over a set of infinite functions. In first case the function $g(x)$ is continuous but in the second case it may not be.

First question you can solve easily. For $n = 2$ $g(x) = \max\{f_1(x), f_2(x)\} = \frac{1}{2}\{|f_1(x) + f_2(x)| + (f_1(x) - f_2(x))\}$. As $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous you can prove that $g$ is continuous.

For second case consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = 1 - x^n$ where $x \in [0,1]$ and see that each $f_n$ is continuous but $g$ is discontinuous at $x = 1$

Comment: and why , how would it differ?